# Groovy tokenizer with a variable

Tags: groovy

in a groovy script for soapui 
i have a loop and I'm trying to define two variables with one variable but i don't know is the syntaxe :

in my source file *liste.txt*, i have to fields (id and date) for each **textLine** separated by - , like this :
0D011A2571D4E6FDF290-2021

0D099Z2571D4E6FDF290-2020

```
//locate the source file
File file1 = new File("C:/User/liste.txt") 
List textLine = file1.readLines() 
def (id, date) = textLine.tokenize( '-' ) //it doesn't work here !
```

if i write the string **textLine** manually:

```
def (id, date) = '0D099Z2571D4E6FDF290-2020'.tokenize( '-' )
```

it works, the result is :

id = 0D099Z2571D4E6FDF290

date = 2020

i tried many syntaxes but each time i have an issue...
how to write the variable **textLine** in the tokenizer ? or is there a simplier way to define n varables with 1 variable ?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
new File("C:/User/liste.txt").splitEachLine( '-' ){ 
  if( 2 != it.size() ) return // bail out
  def (id, date) = it
  doSmthWith( id, date )
}
```

Comment: thanks for quick reply, i tried but i have this error : groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script84.doSmthWith() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [0D011A2571D4E6FDF290, 2021] error at line: 5

Comment: `doSmthWith()` should be a method or code of yours. I just put it in as an example ))

Comment: yeah, you right, after i understood, so i wrote this :

static main (args) 
{ new File("C:/User/liste.txt").splitEachLine( '-' )
{ if ( 2 != it.size() ) return // bail out
  def (id, date) = it
def (id, date) = it.tokenize( '-' ) }   }
log.info "ID= " + id
log.info "DATE= " + date //end

but it returns now : Groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class:Script121 error at line:5
what is wrong ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I continued to search and find another trick, I did this :

```
File file1 = new File("C:/User/liste.txt") 
List textLine = file1.readLines() //read toutes les lignes

def Line = textLine.pop() //take the last line

def id = Line [0..19] //split 19 first characteres from Line

def date = Line [21..24] //split characteres from 21 to 24 from Line
```

Results :

current Line : 0D010710C9D4DBC8675B-2024

id = 0D010710C9D4DBC8675B

date= 2024

hope this will help some people.

thanks **injecter** for your help